# Exportar bases de datos: son los datos modificados a nivel de bits

Tags: base-de-datos, lenguaje-agnóstico, encriptación, contraseña

Gracias a mi ultima pregunta sobre contraseñas hasheadas:

**[Función password_verify: Error al comparar contraseñas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65007/funci%C3%B3n-password-verify-error-al-comparar-contrase%C3%B1as)**

Me surge la curiosidad de como funciona un hasheado en PHP.

Citando la web:

> La funcion hashing produce un resultado **único de longitud**
>   **fija**, si por alguna razón u otra, un sólo bits de información es
>   **modificado**, esta obligatoriamente producirá un hash diferente al
>   original.

Entonces ocurre lo siguiente:

> Si aplico el password_hash 100 veces a una valor especifico, devuelve
>   100 resultados diferentes, a pesar de este no haber sido modificado

*¿ó si lo es.?*.

> Sin embargo, la función `password_verify` tiene la capacidad de comparar si el valor introducido en una variable es igual al hash que se posee (guardado o no en una base de datos).

Es aquí donde tomo de referencia mi pregunta, si ya he hasheado un dato (contenido en una base de datos A) y devuelve true al compararse con su hash

*¿Porque al exportarla a otra base de datos (B) este deja de ser valido?*

*¿Acaso los bits que conforman este dato son moificados?*.

> Acoto ademas el hecho de los `hash collision`, cuando dos datos de
>   tipos diferetnes tienen el mismo hash.

Si dos datos pueden generar un mismo hash y colisionar (pues seran iguales en cadena hash), porque al exportar mis datos dejan de ser validos, dando lugar así a que no se cumpla otra cosa que leí:

> Para conocer si el valor hasheado es igual a otro, el algoritmo hashea ambos valores y revisa si las cadenas generadas son iguales.

Revise la liberia passwordLib.php y contiene lo siguiente:

```
if (!function_exists('password_verify')){
    function password_verify($password, $hash){
        return (crypt($password, $hash) === $hash);
    }
}
```

Observo que tiene un crypt de la contraseña y el hash que se posee, por lo tanto si aplica el proceso de encriptar de nuevo la contraseña o en su defecto el valor.

Concluyo con mi pregunta:

**¿Son entonces estos datos modificados (internamente) al pasarse de una base de datos a otra.?**

Comment: ¿A qué DB te refieres? PHP no tiene como requisito una DB y la función referida tampoco... s

Comment: Base de daros = database jeje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Si aplico el password_hash 100 veces a una valor especifico, devuelve 100 resultados diferentes, a pesar de este no haber sido modificado

Una funcion de hashing es deterministica, siempre devuelve lo mismo si la entrada es la misma.

Lo que hay es que `password_hash` de PHP usa un `salt`, es decir que a la entrada le agrega un string (`salt`) que por defecto es aleatorio.

De todas maneras el `salt` se guarda visible (no encriptado/hasheado) como parte del resultado, de manera que `password_verify` puede conocerlo.

> ¿Por qué al exportarla a otra base de datos (B) este deja de ser valido?

No deja de ser válido, y no entiendo por qué lo dices. IGual, estás mezclando peras con naranjas, `password_hash` y  `password_verify` son funciones de PHP que manejan strings. Lo que hagas con esos strings (guardarlos en bases de datos o lo que quieras) es cosa tuya.

Lo de las colisiones no tiene nada que ver.

Deberias explicarnos en detalle cuál es tu problema.

Comment: la cosa fue que tenia una base de datos local con usuarios y contraseñas (hasheadas) lo cambie a un servidor diferente al mio y por supueto exporte las bases de datos, cuando voy a entrar al sistema no me queria dejar, puesto me decia la funcion password_verify que no eran iguales las contraseñas(contrasena y hash) por lo que tuve que volver a hahsear, en la pregunta puse el link del problema.